# Using AWS SDK for Java V1 to assume role. Its not working

Tags: amazon-web-services, sts-securitytokenservice, assume-role

I am trying to assume an aws role to connect to different service. I have following implementation which is not working fine. It is giving me error

> javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Connection reset

Any thoughts on how to fix this?

public static Credentials assumeRole() {

```
    String targetRoleArn = "xxx";
    String assumedRoleName = "xxx";

    String accessKey = "xxx";
    String secretKey = "xxx";
    
    Credentials assumedCredentials = null;      

    AwsBasicCredentials credentials = AwsBasicCredentials.create(accessKey, secretKey);

    StsClient stsClient = StsClient.builder()
            .region(Region.US_EAST_1)
            .credentialsProvider(StaticCredentialsProvider.create(credentials))
            .build();

    try {
        AssumeRoleRequest roleRequest = AssumeRoleRequest.builder()
                .roleArn(targetRoleArn)
                .roleSessionName(assumedRoleName)
                .build();

        AssumeRoleResponse roleResponse = stsClient.assumeRole(roleRequest);

        assumedCredentials = roleResponse.credentials();

    } catch (StsException e) {
        System.err.println(e.getMessage());
        System.exit(1);
    }
    
    return assumedCredentials;
    
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I strongly suggest that you move from **AWS SDK for Java V1** to **AWS SDK for Java V2**, which is considered best practice. V1 is not recommended anymore, as described in this [AWS Page](https://github.com/awsdocs/aws-doc-sdk-examples#aws-sdk-code-examples).

For this use case, there is an example in [AWS Code Lib](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/code-library/latest/ug/what-is-code-library.html) using **AWS SDK for Java V2**. This example perform these tasks:

1. Creates a user that has no permissions.
2. Creates a role and policy that grants Amazon S3 permissions.
3. Creates a role.
4. Grants the user permissions.
5. Gets temporary credentials **by assuming the role**.  Creates an Amazon S3 Service client object with the temporary credentials.
6. Deletes the resources.

See:

[Create an IAM user and assume a role with AWS STS using an AWS SDK](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/code-library/latest/ug/iam_example_iam_Scenario_CreateUserAssumeRole_section.html)

OR full example in GitHub:

https://github.com/awsdocs/aws-doc-sdk-examples/blob/main/javav2/example_code/iam/src/main/java/com/example/iam/IAMScenario.java

This V2 code has been tested many times and works (as all code in AWS Code Library) - as shown here.

[image]

Comment: Thanks. I tried using AWS SDK for Java V2 and now I am getting "avax.net.ssl.SSLException: Connection reset".

        StsClient stsClient = StsClient.builder()
                .region(Region.US_EAST_1)
                .credentialsProvider(StaticCredentialsProvider.create(credentials))
                .build();

 AssumeRoleRequest roleRequest = AssumeRoleRequest.builder()
                    .roleArn(targetRoleArn)
                    .roleSessionName(assumedRoleName)
                    .build();

            AssumeRoleResponse roleResponse = stsClient.assumeRole(roleRequest);

Comment: Try using the exact code and POM file in the example I referenced. That works as shown in my screenshot.

Comment: I am using exact same configuration and still getting avax.net.ssl.SSLException: Connection reset.

Comment: Please updaye your code and show the extact V2 code you are using. You should not be getting a SSLException if you are using the code in the link i posted.

Comment: I have updated the code above in my original post. I am using V2 code here. Seems simple but still getting avax.net.ssl.SSLException: Connection reset error. Not sure whether I need to add some proxy settings to bypass proxy while connecting from localhost or disable SSL somehow.

Comment: Try this more basic STS example. https://github.com/awsdocs/aws-doc-sdk-examples/blob/main/javav2/example_code/sts/src/main/java/com/example/sts/AssumeRole.java

Comment: I am sorry, I didn't see your comments earlier. It was embedded at the bottom and was asking me to show more. Somehow I could not see this earlier. 

I made some progress. Seems like I needed to add my localhost to skip the proxy while connecting to STS Service. However, now I am getting this new error:

software.amazon.awssdk.services.sts.model.StsException: null (Service: Sts, Status Code: 400, Request ID: null)